# How to edit of rows in Excel-VBA - Test Data Generation

Tags: vba, excel, random

I've recorded a macro to create columns in the table I want to use, now I want to input things in each row. I found this piece of code that will ask for number of rows of input and display that many blank rows:

```
Dim j As Long, r As Range  
j = InputBox("type the number of rows to be insered")  
Set r = Range("A2")  
Do  
Range(r.Offset(1, 0), r.Offset(j, 0)).EntireRow.Insert  
Set r = Cells(r.Row + j + 1, 1)  
MsgBox r.Address  
If r.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then Exit Do  
Loop
```

I was wondering how exactly(where in the loop?) do i insert things into these rows based on the columns I have ? Which function lets me that?

Comment: Hypothetically before the `Set r = Cells(r.Row + j + 1,1)` segment you can type in any references you want and do stuff there. What exactly do you want to do? You can "insert things" through references just about anywhere.

Comment: Like I have a columns id, firstname, lastname, date of birth. So like for column first name, I want like a random name chosen from an array of names ? ... date of birth (random dates in a range of dates), a random non-repeatable number for id.

Comment: @JoeLaviano exactly how do I associate it to each column ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim InsertCount As Long
    Dim rIndex As Long

    InsertCount = Int(Application.InputBox("Type the number of rows to be inserted", "Insert Rows", Type:=1))
    If InsertCount <= 0 Then Exit Sub   'Pressed cancel, or entered a negative number

    For rIndex = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
        Rows(rIndex).Resize(InsertCount).Insert
        With Cells(rIndex, "A").Resize(InsertCount)
            MsgBox .Address

            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            '                                                 '
            '   Code goes here to insert data into column A   '
            '                                                 '
            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        End With
    Next rIndex

End Sub
```

You can add additional sections of `With Cells(rIndex, ...` with different column letters to insert data into those columns.

Comment: So if I wanted all of Column A to be "Bob" in "Code goes here" I would do something like `Cells(rIndex, 2).Value = "BOB"` ?

Comment: If you wanted all of Column A to be "Bob" (and only in the newly inserted rows), then you would replace the "Code goes here" comment box with `.Value = "Bob"`